# Make a DIV childrens appears one by one or Randomly on Page load

Tags: jquery

I want to make `<div>` '#it1', '#it2', '#it3' ... '#itX' to load(appear) one by one in random order on the page load.

Got this script:

```
var max = $('#line1').children().length;
var ctr = 1;   
$('#itbg div').css('opacity','0');
setTimeout(delay,1000);
function delay(){
$('#it' + max).delay(1000).css('opacity','1'); // works Only for the Last DIV (#itX)
$('#it' + ctr).delay(1000).css('opacity','1'); // works Only for the First DIV (#it1)
}
```

And HTML like this

```
<div id="line1">
<div id="item">
<div id="itbg">
<div id="it1">content</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="item">
<div id="itbg">
<div id="it2">content2</div>
</div></div>
<div id="item">
<div id="itbg">
<div id="it3">content2</div>
</div></div>
</div>
```

In which way I must dig to figure it out? I need #it1, #it2, #it3..#itX to appear in random order one by one or just one by one(directly). And the fiddle of this code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BejhK/).

Comment: What is the motivation to do this? Seems rather weird

Comment: yeah its odd. i want to show Logo at the background of (category)Page before Catalog is loaded. #page {background-image:...};

Comment: So not in a random order!

Comment: but one by one, not All at Once

Comment: tell me in which order do you want to shoe them , may be ican help

Comment: fromt first to the next (1,2,3...n) or random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one will not affect with the numbers of your IT You can have 1000 of them  :D

```
            var i = 1;
        $.each($("div[id^='it']"), function () {
            $(this).delay(1000 + (i * 100)).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 1000);
            i++;
        });
```

Comment: yeah thanks. is `div[id^=it']` means all DIVs who have ID 'it' and/or it1, it2, it#? just to understand it well

Comment: it means all div with it's id starts with it :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to collect a list of your items, then scramble the list, then make the items appear:

```
var max = $('#line1').children().length;
var ctr = 1; 
var i,j,k,t,next;

// items in order (ex. [1,2,3,4,5,6])

var itms=[];
for(i=1;i<=max;i++)
    itms.push(i);  

// now scramble the items randomly (ex. [6,2,3,1,2,4,5])

for(i=0;i<max;i++)
{          
    // choose two items randomly
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    k = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    // swap
    t = itms[j];                
    itms[j] = itms[k];
    itms[k] = t;
}

// fade in one item at time (following the scrambled list)

fadeIn(0, max, itms);

function fadeIn(current, max, itmsList)
{
    $('#it' + itmsList[current]).fadeIn(1000);
    if(current<max)
    {
        setTimeout( function() {fadeIn(current + 1,max,itmsList);}, 1000);
    }
}
```

Note that you have a bad mistake in your html: more elements with same **id**

Rewrite like this:

```
<div id="line1">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itbg">
            <div id="it1">content1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itbg">
            <div id="it2">content2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itbg">
            <div id="it3">content3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itbg">
            <div id="it4">content4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itbg">
            <div id="it5">content5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally adjust your CSS in a way that items of class **itbg** are not visible initially.

```
.itbg div {
    border:1px solid grey;
    display: none;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pV55k/

Comment: Thanks a lot! works fine.UP: This works fine. But delaying <opacity> from 0 to 1 looks prettier

Comment: So i changed fadeIn function

Answer (score 0):

at first you have to set the opacity to 0
then you can change it to "1" in One second , SO it will be like this :
if you have already change the opacity to zero you can eliminate the code which change the opacity to ZERO :D 
this  Jquery just work on your HTML :D

```
 $(function () {
        max = new Array();
        $.each($('#line1 > #item > #itbg').children(), function () {
            //here it change the opacity to ZERO
            $(this).animate({'opacity' : '0'},1);
            max.push($(this));
        });

      $(max[0]).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 1000, function () {
            $(max[1]).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 1000, function () {
                $(max[2]).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 1000, function () {
                    $(max[3]).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 1000, function () {
                        $(max[4]).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 1000);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nice, looks greate. TY!

Comment: if u want to do that u have to  write another  $(max[2]).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 1000); in the call back of the last animate

Comment: works but its gonna be a very huge line of code, if there will be 30 or 40 #it...I cant give you a plus because i dont have enough Rep to do that.

Comment: I have added another soloution which doesnot affet with the number og #IT

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you want to keep the current structure you can just find the ids similar with [regex in the selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and apply your css opacity change.

```
function delay(){
    $("div[id^='it']").delay(1000).css('opacity','1');
}
```

I hope this helps. Unfortunately jQuery does not have such a good regex so you cant find it + a number so it searches for string that starts with 'it'.